# Unexpected behaviour with FileInputStream, JAVA

Tags: java, performance, filesystems, operating-system, fileinputstream

I am in the process of writing an application that processes a huge number of integers from a binary file (up to 50 meg). I need to do it as quickly as possible and the main performance issue is the disk access time, since I make a large number of reads from the disk, optimizing read time would improve performance of the app in general.

Up until now I thought that the fewer blocks I split my file into (i.e. the fewer reads I have / the larger the read size is) the faster my app should work. This is because HDD is very slow on seeking i.e. locating the beginning of the block due to its mechanical nature. However, once it locates the beginning of the block you asked it to read off it should perform the actual read fairly quickly.

Well, that was up until I ran this test:

> Old test removed, had issues due to HDD Caching

NEW TEST (HDD Cache doesn't help here since the file is too big (1gb) and I access random locations within it):

```
    int mega = 1024 * 1024;
    int giga = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    byte[] bigBlock = new byte[mega];
    int hundredKilo = mega / 10;
    byte[][] smallBlocks = new byte[10][hundredKilo];
    String location = "C:\\Users\\Vladimir\\Downloads\\boom.avi";
    RandomAccessFile raf;
    FileInputStream f;
    long start;
    long end;
    int position;
    java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
    int bigBufferTotalReadTime = 0;
    int smallBufferTotalReadTime = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        position = rand.nextInt(giga);
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(location, "r");
        raf.seek((long) position);
        f = new FileInputStream(raf.getFD());
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        f.read(bigBlock);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        bigBufferTotalReadTime += end - start;
        f.close();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        position = rand.nextInt(giga);
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(location, "r");
        raf.seek((long) position);
        f = new FileInputStream(raf.getFD());
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            f.read(smallBlocks[i]);
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        smallBufferTotalReadTime += end - start;
        f.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Average performance of small buffer: " + (smallBufferTotalReadTime / 100));
    System.out.println("Average performance of big buffer: " + (bigBufferTotalReadTime / 100));
```

RESULTS:
Average for small buffer - 35ms
Average for large buffer - 40ms ?!
(Tried on linux and windows, in both cases larger block size results in longer read time, why?)

After running this test for many many times I have realised that for some magical reason reading one big block takes on average longer than reading 10 blocks of smaller size sequentially. I thought that it might have been a result of Windows being too smart and trying to optimize something in its file system, so I ran the same code on Linux and to my surprise I got the same result.

I have no clue as to why this is happening, could anyone please give me a hint? Also what would be the best block size in this case?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read the data the first time, the data will be in disk cache.  The second read should be much faster.  You need to run the test you think is faster first. ;)

If you have 50 MB of memory, you should be able to read the entire file at once.

---

```
package com.google.code.java.core.files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class FileReadingMain {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        File temp = File.createTempFile("deleteme", "zeros");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        fos.write(new byte[50 * 1024 * 1024]);
        fos.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int blockSize = 1024 * 1024; blockSize >= 512; blockSize /= 2) {
                readFileNIO(temp, blockSize);
                readFile(temp, blockSize);
            }
    }

    private static void readFile(File temp, int blockSize) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[blockSize];
        int r;
        for (r = 0; System.nanoTime() - start < 2e9; r++) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(temp);
            while (fis.read(bytes) > 0) ;
            fis.close();
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("IO: Reading took %.3f ms using %,d byte blocks%n", time / r / 1e6, blockSize);
    }

    private static void readFileNIO(File temp, int blockSize) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(blockSize);
        int r;
        for (r = 0; System.nanoTime() - start < 2e9; r++) {
            FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(temp).getChannel();
            while (fc.read(bytes) > 0) {
                bytes.clear();
            }
            fc.close();
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("NIO: Reading took %.3f ms using %,d byte blocks%n", time / r / 1e6, blockSize);
    }
}
```

On my laptop prints

```
NIO: Reading took 57.255 ms using 1,048,576 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 112.943 ms using 1,048,576 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 48.860 ms using 524,288 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 78.002 ms using 524,288 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 41.474 ms using 262,144 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 61.744 ms using 262,144 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 41.336 ms using 131,072 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 56.264 ms using 131,072 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 42.184 ms using 65,536 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 64.700 ms using 65,536 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 41.595 ms using 32,768 byte blocks <= fastest for NIO
IO: Reading took 49.385 ms using 32,768 byte blocks <= fastest for IO
NIO: Reading took 49.676 ms using 16,384 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 59.731 ms using 16,384 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 55.596 ms using 8,192 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 74.191 ms using 8,192 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 77.148 ms using 4,096 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 84.943 ms using 4,096 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 104.242 ms using 2,048 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 112.768 ms using 2,048 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 177.214 ms using 1,024 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 185.006 ms using 1,024 byte blocks
NIO: Reading took 303.164 ms using 512 byte blocks
IO: Reading took 316.487 ms using 512 byte blocks
```

It appears that the optimal read size may be 32KB. Note: as the file is entirely in disk cache this may not be the optimal size for a file which is read from disk.

Comment: PS I don't have 50 MB of memory :))

Comment: But you have a HDD?? Is this a mobile device with a memory card?

Comment: "You need to run the test you think is faster first"

Comment: Nah, this is an algorithm that will be limited to a certain amount of RAM and whoever comes up with the fastest one, wins :)

Comment: If you have a mobile device, you need to test what is the optimal block size for your device.  I would start with 8K which is reasonable even on a PC or server. If you have a memory card, the size of the block is less likely to be important.

Comment: In that case, use as much memory as you can. Unless using less memory is a bonus. ;)

Comment: But should it not be fastest with the largest block size since the head of the disk will need to locate the beginning of a block fewer times?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "use as much memory as you can"

Comment: Peter could you please have a look at the NEW TEST? I have a workaround to trick HDD cache now.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Larger block take longer because the you have the average seek time and the transfer time. The transfer time is proportional to the size. If a small block takes 35 ms and a large block 40 ms, but the small block is 10x smaller, you need to spend 350 ms to read the same amount data.

Comment: not quite, I am measuring the time it takes to read 1 mb using small blocks vs large block, reading one mb with small blocks is faster than reading the same amount with a large block

Comment: You may be getting better use of L3 cache with the smaller buffer.  Also, predictive read-ahead may get a little bit of a head start with the smaller buffer.  BTW... I wouldn't use a random position - it just makes one more thing that you don't know.

Comment: The optimal size appears to be 32 KB for my system. Its L2 cache is 1 MB but the L1 cache is 32 KB.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I would love to know why this "parabolic" behaviour is occurring though =) It is clear that when the blocks are too small the seeking overhead is killing the speed. I would like to know what is causing the damn thing to perform worse with a large block size.
@Ed, are you referring to the OS or the HDD internal controller?

Comment: @Vlad, for L3 cache, I meant CPU; for predictive read-ahead, it could be anywhere/everywhere.  I'm no hardware maven.

Comment: When the file is in disk cache, it is the memory to memory transfer which matters. It would appear the size of L1 cache is critical.  If the data is being read from disk, you will see the behaviour of the disk come into play.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, your test is hopelessly compromised by reading the same data for each.

I could spew on, but you'll probably get more out of reading [this article,](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly) then looking at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UsingFileChanneltoreadtextfile.htm) of how to use FileChannel.

Comment: nice article, thanks, will have a look at it in the morning with a clear head! :)

Comment: Of course, your mileage _will_ differ.  Also, there's a lot of argument about whether FileChannel really is faster, and if it is, under what conditions using what techniques.  You can find something on the web supporting virtually any opinion about it, other than reads that finish before they start.

Comment: OK, it turns out we are prohibited from using FileChannel :(

Comment: 'prohibited' by whom?  The FilePolice?

Comment: Hahaha, no :). It is a competition for writing an algorithm and we are not allowed to use FileChannel for our solutions to qualify.